# Remotely sending inputs to a running Python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'll try to be as clear as possible with what I'm trying to aim for.
I have a running Python script on my Raspberry Pi and I'd like **multiple users** to send inputs to the script remotely (through SSH or anything else that might work better).
So for example if I have this script running:

```
Name = input ("Please type in your name. \n")
type (Name)
print ("Hello there" , Name)
time.sleep(3) # Pause for 3 seconds.
```

I want users to send names to this script remotely from devices that are connected to the same network as the Raspberry Pi.

If possible, I also want to implement the following functionalities:

- Sending the output (aka the printed text) back to the specific device the input came from.
- A queuing system: If multiple users send names at the same time, the script will take the names in order, one by one.

***I know it's a lot to ask for, but I'd really appreciate if someone could help me get started with this by pointing me in the right direction.*** I've searched around quite a bit for the past few days but I haven't really come across anything that fits my needs.

Edit: I'm running this on PYTHON 3

Comment: It would help if you explained what your script is for and how you imagine it to deal with multiple concurrent users.

Comment: @IrmendeJong - The script is very long and it would impractical to post it all for this question. But basically, the script will take an input from users (_Name_) and send an output ("_Hello there Irmen_") back to those users.
As for concurrency, I hope I can find a way to queue all the names in a buffer-like system (or list), where the Python Script will go through the buffer of names and send back outputs, one-by-one. Meaning: If A, B, and C send their names at the same time, the script will first take A, send output, pause for 3 seconds, then move to B and then C.
**Did that clarify?**

Comment: I'm sorry but no, not really - it is more or less a rephrasing your original question. I was looking for details wrt how the script is executed, for instance: do you have a server, is it executed as a long running server process or maybe invoked by some other means, how does it talk to the outside world such as is it reading from stdin only or are you able to process network connections.

Comment: @IrmendeJong - The script is running on a Raspberry Pi, so that would serve as the server. The script is simply started when the Raspberry boots up. As for how it communicates with the outside world... Well that's the trouble I'm having. I can't really input data into the script nor can I receive output from it unless I'm connected to the Raspberry via SSH. I was using stdin for a while to forward commands, that sent to the terminal (via SSH), to the script. But this proved to be inefficient and I'm hoping to find a way to communicate with the script **directly**.

Comment: And I'm fairly certain I can process network connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment that you would like to communicate (via network) to the script directly, opens up a world of possibilities. You have to modify your Python script a little though, because it won't communicate via stdin/stdout any longer.

I'm still not entirely sure how you want things to work but it does sound to me that a solution based around RPC can possibly work for you. May I suggest you have a look at [Pyro4](http://pyro4.readthedocs.io)?    Basically what that does for you is enable you to do normal Python method calls, but over the network, to code running on another computer.

So you can set up a server on your Pi (that needs to run continuously) which accepts remote calls from other computers, and can then call into your python code on the pi. It can process calls in parallel or in sequence.  You didn't say if you need any form of security, but some basic security features are provided (no built-in encryption or communication over TLS yet, sorry).

[A simple example is here](http://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#simple-example)   and lots more are on github so you can have a look to see if this fits your requirements?

Another solution that doesn't require third party libraries is perhaps to write a [WSGI](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server) http server that calls your script, run this on the pi, and access it via HTTP from your other computers.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even know such a Library existed. It seems like you're the person who has developed it, so kudos to you! The WSGI Server feature is also an eye-opener.
From what I've read, I'm not sure if I'll be able to distinguish between multiple user inputs (i.e WHO sent WHAT), so I can send back a personalized answer. But I will definitely read up and see what can be done!
Thanks for putting me on the right path!

Comment: You are correct. Also, the Wsgi server solution is just a fancy way of creating a web server in Python that runs an application instead of serving static pages, and so, it's processing the data from every connected 'user' as separate requests that each have their own context